# Statistics earthquake probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a site located in the proximity of three seismically active faults, as shown in Figure. Suppose an earthquake may occur as a 30 km rupture along any of the faults. Based on the size and previous activity of each fault, it is estimated that the likelihoods of occurrence of the earthquake on faults 1, 2 and 3 are proportional to 2, 3 and 5, respectively, i.e., fault 2 is one-and-half times more likely to produce the earthquake than fault 1, and so on. We assume within each fault the rupture can occur anywhere within the fault with equal likelihood. We are interested in determining the probability that in the event the earthquake occurs, the distance from the site to the nearest point on the fault rupture will be less than 50 km.[image]

I feel like the wording of this question is very confusing...can someone explain to me what this question is asking? and how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, yeah, that is a awkwardly constructed problem, with some awkwardly chosen constants to boot, I think.

We can dispense with the overall faults fairly easily.  Since they produce earthquakes in the proportion $2:3:5$, the actual probabilities are $2/x, 3/x, 5/x$, where $x$ is chosen so that the three probabilities sum to $1$.  This you should be able to do fairly quickly.

Next, you must find the proportion of each fault that lies within $50$ km of the site—which, annoyingly, is not a point but a square, and the problem doesn't specify what point on the site is to be referenced.  Since the size of the site isn't given (and neither is the angle of the third fault), we'll assume that the reference points are given for the fault: upper left corner for the first fault, center of the right side for the second fault, and lower right corner for the third fault.  We assume further that the third fault is perpendicular to the $20$ km "leg" drawn out to it.

Consider the first fault: The nearest point must be within $50$ km, which means $20$ km north and $\sqrt{50^2-20^2} = 10\sqrt{21} \doteq 45.8$ km west.  That means $45.8-30 = 15.8$ km from the easternmost point on the fault.  The easternmost point on the fault, in turn, is uniformly chosen over an interval of $80-30 = 50$ km (the length of the fault $80$ km, minus the length of the rupture $30$ km).  Therefore, the probability that the nearest point is within $50$ km, *given that the first fault is the one that quakes*, is $P_1 = 15.8/50 = 0.316$ (to the nearest thousandth).

Find similar quantities for $P_2$ and $P_3$, the probabilities that the nearest point is within $50$ km, *given that the second or third fault is the one that quakes*, respectively.  Careful with the third fault, since the desired interval may not extend to one end.  Then the final probability desired is

$$
P = \frac{2}{x} P_1 + \frac{3}{x} P_2 + \frac{5}{x} P_3
$$

Not a very elegant problem, in my opinion.